# How to change the "timestamp without time zone" to "timestamp with time zone" using Django models using migrations?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, pgadmin

```
 class test(models.Model):
      mobile_last_login = models.DateTimeField()
```

I need to change the "timestamp without time zone" to "timestamp with time zone" for the "mobile_last_login" field.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a timezone to `DateTimeField` - Django store date-time in UTC if you have set `USE_TZ = True` in your settings, or naive date time otherwise. If `USE_TZ` is set, then Django will automatically apply timezone offset, according to your settings, one's data is fetched from DB.

If you really need to store the timezone, probably an easiest solution will be to store it as a separate field:

```
import pytz


class test(models.Model):  
    TIMEZONE_CHOICES = tuple(zip(pytz.all_timezones, pytz.all_timezones))
    
    mobile_last_login = models.DateTimeField()
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=TIMEZONE_CHOICES, default=str(pytz.utc))
```